# python xml parsing

Tags: python, xml

I have to delete particular tags from an xml file. Sample xml below.

```
       <data>
          <tag:action/>
        </data>
```

I want to delete all contents between data and /data. The XML tags are not displayed in the question after posting.

I am able to do this by using remove() method in Python ElementTree xml parser. I am writing the modified contents to a new after the deletion of the element.

```
tree.write('new.xml');
```

The problem is that all the tag names in the original xml file are renamed to `ns0`, `ns1` and so on in `new.xml`.

Is there any way to modify the XML file keeping all other contents in tact?

Comment: That looks like an incomplete XML file to me. How would lxml know what namespace to associate with `tag`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use beautiful soup to do the job :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import bs4

content = '''
<people>

  <person born="1975">
    <name>
      <first_name>John</first_name>
      <last_name>Doe</last_name>
    </name>
    <profession>computer scientist</profession>
    <homepage href="http://www.example.com/johndoe"/>
  </person>

  <person born="1977">
    <name>
      <first_name>Jane</first_name>
      <last_name>Doe</last_name>
    </name>
    <profession>computer scientist</profession>
    <homepage href="http://www.example.com/janedoe"/>
  </person>

</people>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for s in soup('name'):
    s.extract()

print(soup)
```

It produces the following result :

```
<html><body><people>
<person born="1975">

<profession>computer scientist</profession>
<homepage href="http://www.example.com/johndoe"></homepage>
</person>
<person born="1977">

<profession>computer scientist</profession>
<homepage href="http://www.example.com/janedoe"></homepage>
</person>
</people>
</body></html>
```

With namespaces :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import bs4

content = '''<people xmlns:h="http://www.example.com/to/">

  <h:person born="1975">
    <h:name>
      <h:first_name>John</h:first_name>
      <h:last_name>Doe</h:last_name>
    </h:name>
    <h:profession>computer scientist</h:profession>
    <h:homepage href="http://www.example.com/johndoe"/>
  </h:person>

  <h:person born="1977">
    <h:name>
      <h:first_name>Jane</h:first_name>
      <h:last_name>Doe</h:last_name>
    </h:name>
    <h:profession>computer scientist</h:profession>
    <h:homepage href="http://www.example.com/janedoe"/>
  </h:person>

</people>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content).people

for s in soup('h:name'):
    s.extract()

print(soup)
```

I added `.people` to prevent `<html><body>`
`</body></html>` in the result.

```
<people xmlns:h="http://www.example.com/to/">
<h:person born="1975">

<h:profession>computer scientist</h:profession>
<h:homepage href="http://www.example.com/johndoe"></h:homepage>
</h:person>
<h:person born="1977">

<h:profession>computer scientist</h:profession>
<h:homepage href="http://www.example.com/janedoe"></h:homepage>
</h:person>
</people>
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I got it working with beautifulsoup.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I got it working with beautifulsoup. But, there are namespaces in XML tags. How can I search for a particular tag if namespace is present. I used find and find_all, but its not returning the values.